# Add conditions within a simple calculation

Tags: conditional-statements, spss

I calculated a simple addition but want to add a condition in it;

```
1*(acute_miorhistory_mi) +
1*(chf) +
1*(pvd) +
1*(cvd) +
1*(copd) +
1*(dementia) +
2*(paralysis) +
1*(diabetes) +
2*(diabetes_comp) +
2*(renal_disease) +
1*(mild_liver_disease) +
3*(liver_disease) +
1*(ulcers) +
1*(rheum_disease) +
6*(aids) + 
2*(carcinoma) +
6*(metacancer).
```

what I want to do is to:
not add diabetes if diabetes_comp exists
not add mild_liver_disease if liver_disease exist
not to add carcinoma if metacancer exists.
so how to add if command here?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "if diabetes_comp exists"? In general when you post questions in Stack-Overflow (btw - welcome!) you should  try to add an example - the structure of your data, the code you've been using, the expected results. This would make it easier for us to understand the problem and suggest relevant solutions.

Comment: sorry i failed to mention..these variables can either be zero or 1, if e.g carcinoma is 1 and metacancer is also one, i want the equation to ignore the carcinoma..

Comment: what you should do is edit your original post and add the information there. BTW, why are you multiplying variables by 1 ?

Comment: you are right i dont need to multiply by 1 but some variables its more than 1, so i can simplify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a nice way to add the conditions you need without changing the structure of your original command.
So the condition for adding carcinoma is that metacancer doesn't exist, or if `carcinoma=0`. In spss you can use `(carcinoma=0)` as a numerical value of 0 (true) or 1 (false):

```
1*(acute_miorhistory_mi) +
. . .
1*(diabetes)*(diabetes_comp=0) +
2*(diabetes_comp) +
2*(renal_disease) +
1*(mild_liver_disease)*(liver_disease=0) +
3*(liver_disease) +
. . .
2*(carcinoma)*(metacancer=0) +
6*(metacancer).
```

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed a smart way to do it !